# Auto cancel changes in DataForm when selection is changed

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, currency, toolkit, dataform

I wonder how you do such thing. Assume, we have MVVM CRUD app which modifies a tree (menu structure, for example). We have a view model with the menu items and two views: the first with a `TreeView` and the second with a `DataForm`. Main problems are:

1. `DataForm` can not handle
   hierarchical data.
2. Depending on the menu item selected
   in the `TreeView` the `DataForm`
   should display different set of
   fields (for example for menu items
   with children or without).

I've ended up with the following. View model has 3 fields:

1. `Items` — the collection of
   `MenuItem` objects which have their
   own `Children` collection for
   building hierarchical data source.
2. `SelectedItem` — currently selected
   `MenuItem` in the `TreeView`.
3. `EditedItem` — `EditViewModel`
   object which basically has two
   descendants: `MenuItemEditViewModel`
   and `LeafMenuItemEditViewModel`.
   This property is set automatically
   when `SelectedItem` is changed. Its
   actual type is inferred from the
   `SelectedItem.Children` emptiness.

`TreeView` is bound to `Items` and `SelectedItem`. `DataForm` is not required to maintain currency in this case (instead current item is set by the `TreeView`) nor it is responsible for creating and deleting items. That's why I decided to bind only its `CurrentItem` to view model's `EditedItem` (`ItemsSource` is unbound). Its `AutoCommit` is set to `False` (when it is `True` and `ItemsSource` is unbound all current item changes get copied to newly selected item when you select different item in the `TreeView`, which is not so nice). `DataForm` fields are autogenerated.

Obviously, that now if we select an item in the `TreeView`, then make some changes in the `DataForm` and try to select different item in the `TreeView` we'll get well-known

> Cannot change currency when an item
>   has validation errors or it is being
>   edited and AutoCommit is false. Set
>   ItemsSource to a ICollectionView to
>   manage currency instead

In this case I want `DataForm` to discard all changes implicitly. There is a workaround to call `DataForm.CancelEdit()` before `TreeView` selected item is changed (usually an event like `PreviewSelectionChanged` or `BeforeSelectionChanged`). But it is not the MVVM way since the `TreeView` and the `DataForm` are defined in completely different views (read: is not acceptable).

Is there something like AutoCancel which forces `DataForm` to cancel changes when its `CurrentItem` is changed? Maybe someone from dev team can answer? Or how would you deal with such problem?

Comment: The error message is clear: you need to stick with dollars.  You can't switch to euros while an item is being edited and AutoCommit is false! :)

Answer (score 4):

I was surprised to find the Silverlight is severly lacking in this functionality, considering all the business oriented RIA functionality.  AutoCommit is not acceptable to me because I want the user to explicitly acknowledge pending changes, rather than just commit something to the database that they may not want.

You can reliably track the edit mode of the DataForm using a private member variable and trapping the BeginningEdit and EditEnded events of the DataForm (naming inconsistency!  Why one is called xxxEdit and the others are Editxxx is beyond me.  Should it not be *EditBeginning* and EditEnded??).  Inside the event handler for BeginningEdit, set the flag to true and set it to false in EditEnded.

In your SelectionChanged event, you can then check the flag.  If it is true, you can call the CancelEdit on the DataForm.

```
private bool _editing = false;

public MainPage() {
    DataForm1.BeinningEdit += 
        new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(DataForm1_BeginningEdit);
    DataForm1.EditEnded += 
        new EventHandler<DataFormEditEndedEventArgs>(DataForm1_EditEnded);
}

protected void DataForm1_BeginningEdit(object sender, 
    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    _editing = true;
}

protected void DataForm1_EditEnded(object sender, 
    DataFormEditEndedEventArgs e) {
    _editing = false;
}

void TreeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, 
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (_editing) {
        object previous = DataForm1.SelectedItem;
        object current = TreeView1.SelectedItem;

        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel the changes?", 
            "Confirm", MessageBoxbutton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK) {
            DataForm1.CancelEdit();
        }
        else {
            TreeView1.SelectedItem = previous;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx! But I've already changed DataForm source to meet my needs. And I definitely like your suggestion about asking user confirmation (in my current situation all changes are canceled if user have not explicitly saved them).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set AutoCommit at True ?

Comment: Yep, it's not a solution. I mentioned it: "when it is True and ItemsSource is unbound all current item changes get copied to newly selected item when you select different item in the TreeView, which is not so nice"